# getting the array info with the GET method

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I am using multiple select field to send the data and fetch it with the GET method.

```
.change(function(event){

 if(event.target == this){
 emails=$(this).val();
 }
     $("#button_list").click(function(){
 window.location.replace("http://mysite.php?email="+emails);
 }); 
 });
```

In the adress bar I GET the following information:

```
mysite.php?emails=email1@domain1.com,email2@domain2.com
```

Actually I am getting multiple email adresses data in one variable $emails separated only with commas.

How could I separate this information in order to able to send emails to every each email address in the address bar.

Thanks

Comment: use `POST ` instead of `GET`

Comment: `GET` should separate with `&` mark

Comment: Why dont you use a simple HTML `form`? it seems like your jQuery isnt doing anything special.

Comment: Why do you use this condition `if (event.target == this)` I am just wondering

Comment: You could try the _email[]_ format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split the emails string into separate email addresses:

`$emails_array = explode(',', $_GET['emails']);`

Use it to send each email:

`foreach ($emails_array AS $email) { // do the email sending }`

Answer (score 0):

You could just create a proper querystring using `jQuery.param`

```
.change(function(event){
    if(event.target == this){
        var emails = $(this).val();
        var data   = emails.split(',').map(function(item) { return {name : 'emails', value : item} });
        var params = $.param(data);
    }
     $("#button_list").click(function(){
        window.location.replace("http://mysite.php?" + params);
    }); 
});
```

Now you end up with the URL

```
http://mysite.php?emails=email1%40domain1.com&emails=email2%40domain2.com
```

and you can access the emails as an array with `$_GET['emails']` on the server

---

Should be noted that just using a regular form would accomplish this without javascript at all, and that you should generally never put an event handler inside another event handler

Comment: hello @adeneo, I have a question, why is this condition used: `if (event.target == this)`

Comment: It checks that the `event.target`, the element the event fired on, is the same as the bound element (`this`). It's done to avoid running the code inside the if condition if the event bubbled up from a child element

Answer (score 0):

Even though you accepted an answer. I will still post my answer in hopes to teach you something. You are using jQuery , but I keep asking myself *"why?"* Also, why have the condition `if (event.target == this)` .. I believe you dont even need jquery at all to accomplish what you are trying to do. All you have to do is use a `form` with the proper elements using the `name` attribute. This is all you need:

**HTML:**

```
<form action="mysite.php">
    <select name="emails">
        <option value="email1@domain1.com,email2@domain2.com">one</option>
        <option value="email3@domain3.com,email4@domain4.com">two</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit"></button>
</form>
```

**PHP:**

```
$emails = $_GET['emails'];
$emails_arr = explode(",", $emails);
foreach ($emails_arr as $email) {
    echo $email;
}
```